# pd.concat throws a ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I've got an error merging two dataframes by row. The last version I used `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)`, but in pandas version 2.1.0 doesn't work. Anybody knows how to solve the error?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 2
      1 print(real_last.shape, real_exp.shape) #(59202, 34) (4583, 34)
----> 2 real_out = pd.concat([real_exp, real_last], axis=0)
      3 print(real_out.shape)

File c:\Users\sarud\anaconda3\envs\ETLupdate\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:393, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    378     copy = False
    380 op = _Concatenator(
    381     objs,
    382     axis=axis,
   (...)
    390     sort=sort,
    391 )
--> 393 return op.get_result()

File c:\Users\sarud\anaconda3\envs\ETLupdate\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:680, in _Concatenator.get_result(self)
    676             indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
    678     mgrs_indexers.append((obj._mgr, indexers))
...
--> 230 return super()._concat_same_type(to_concat, axis=axis)

File arrays.pyx:190, in pandas._libs.arrays.NDArrayBacked._concat_same_type()

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 4583 and the array at index 1 has size 59202
```

I have the packages:
`print(sys.version, pd.__version__, np.__version__, sep='\n')`

```
3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:26:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
2.1.0
1.26.0
```

The dataframes has the same structure, check a sample:

```
print(real_last.sample(2).T.to_markdown())
```

|  | 43597 | 9338 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orden | 006710000 | 006781111 |
| Operacion | 0010 | 0020 |
| Operacion.text | XXXXXX | YYYYYYY |
| Cl.orden | NP | NP |
| Cl.actividad | 030 | 035 |
| Ubic.tecnica | XXXX-XX-LAS-DES-BAP19 | XXXX-XX-S13-MBA |
| Status.sistema | CTEC NOTI IMOP KKMP PREC | LIB. IMOP KKMP PREC |
| Status.sistema.op | NOTI CONT CTEC NLIQ | LIB. NLIQ |
| Stat.Usuario | TRAT | TRAT |
| Fe.Entrada | 2023-06-25 00:00:00 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Lib | 2023-07-06 00:00:00 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Ini.real.ot | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | NaT |
| Fe.Ini.real.op | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | NaT |
| Fe.Ini.temp | 2023-07-06 00:00:00 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| Aviso | 00120100 | 11194911 |
| Modif.por | XXXXX005 | XXXXX011 |
| Fe.Modif | 2023-07-06 00:00:00 | 2023-07-23 00:00:00 |
| Autor | XXXXX003 | XXXXX021 |
| Grupo.planif | XXT | XX1 |
| G.hojas.ruta | nan | nan |
| CGH | nan | nan |
| Plan.mant.prev | nan | nan |
| Pos.PM | nan | nan |
| Pto.tbjo.resp | XXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXX |
| Pto.tbjo.op | XXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXX |
| Cantidad | 1 | 0 |
| Duracion.normal | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| Trabajo | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| Trabajo.real | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| Costos tot.reales | 147.03 | 0.0 |
| Sum.costo.plan | 147.03 | 479.96 |
| Tot.plan.general | 147.03 | 479.96 |
| Total.real.general | 147.03 | 0.0 |
| Costo.dist | 0.0 | 0.0 |

`print(real_exp.sample(2).T.to_markdown())`

|  | 926 | 990 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orden | 222212222 | 333323333 |
| Operacion | 0120 | 0040 |
| Operacion.text | XXXXXXXXXX | YYYYYYYYY |
| Cl.orden | PL | PL |
| Cl.actividad | 010 | 010 |
| Ubic.tecnica | XXXX-XX-S07-ALI-CTR7B | XXXX-XX-SCA-AL2-AOG1C |
| Status.sistema | CTEC NOTI IMPR FMAT IMOP MOVM NLIQ PREC* | LIB. NOTI IMPR DOCU IMOP KKMP NLIQ PREC* |
| Status.sistema.op | NOTI CTEC IMPR NLIQ | NOTI CONT IMPR LIB. NLIQ PLAN |
| Stat.Usuario | TBTR | TRAT |
| Fe.Entrada | 2023-08-02 00:00:00 | 2023-08-02 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Lib | 2023-08-23 00:00:00 | 2023-08-21 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Ini.real.ot | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Ini.real.op | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 |
| Fe.Ini.temp | 2023-09-07 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 |
| Aviso | 33333333 | 44444444 |
| Modif.por | XXXXX009 | XXXXX003 |
| Fe.Modif | 2023-09-10 00:00:00 | 2023-09-07 00:00:00 |
| Autor | XXXXXXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXXXXXX |
| Grupo.planif | XX0 | XXC |
| G.hojas.ruta | 1886 | 76326 |
| CGH | 3 | 3 |
| Plan.mant.prev | 8763 | 191111 |
| Pos.PM | 95475 | 357140 |
| Pto.tbjo.resp | XXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXX |
| Pto.tbjo.op | XXXXXXXX | XXXXXXXX |
| Cantidad | 4 | 2 |
| Duracion.normal | 4.0 | 1.0 |
| Trabajo | 16.0 | 2.0 |
| Trabajo.real | 16.0 | 0.5 |
| Costos tot.reales | 1627.5 | 0.04 |
| Sum.costo.plan | 2336.45 | 0.09 |
| Tot.plan.general | 2336.45 | 0.09 |
| Total.real.general | 1627.5 | 0.04 |
| Costo.dist | nan | nan |

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `df1`/`df2`?

Comment: I updated the post with a sample of both dataframes

Comment: `df1.join(df2, how='outer')`

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't trigger the `ValueError` with the given examples but, since your dataframes hold datetimes values, this could be maybe due to a *dtypes* and/or *resolution mismatch* like in this [*Q/A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77045855/). You can also check [GH55067](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55067) that discusses a similar issue.

Try this :

```
real_out = pd.concat([real_exp, real_last.astype(real_exp.dtypes)], axis=0)
```

Output :

```
print(real_out)

           Orden Operacion  ... Total.real.general Costo.dist
926    222212222      0120  ...             1627.5        NaN
990    333323333      0040  ...               0.04        NaN
43597  006710000      0010  ...             147.03        0.0
9338   006781111      0020  ...                0.0        0.0

[4 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: it works, thanks!

Comment: I checked the dtypes and there are difference between datetime columns, there are two formats datetime64[us] and datetime64[ns]