# why concat(axis=0) doesn't work ? in python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm having a problem with convert from jupyternote to python with this statement

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
```

suppose I have  2 dataframe
df_a =

| date_time | grp | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-02-01 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-03-01 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-02-01 | B | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-03-01 | B | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| ..... | .... | .... | .... | .... |

where data size equal (300,5)

and df_2 =

| date_time | grp | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2024-02-01 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2024-03-01 | A | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2024-01-01 | B | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2024-02-01 | B | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2024-03-01 | B | NaN | NaN | NaN |

where size is (6,5)

both have same data types and I just want to concatatenate data vertically

```
df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)
```

This I try on jupyter notebook book work normally when I try convert script into python the program encounter this error

all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 300 and the array at index 1 has size 6

I would like to know what should I do?

Comment: concat will create a DataFrame with shape `(306, 5)`. Is this what you want? If not, **what is the exact expected output**? It looks to me that you might rather want a `merge`.

Comment: Yes, I want to concat into shape (306,5) as a result. Since I want to append data directly (no matching index need) 

I test with jupyter notebook this code is fine but when convert to as a part python script it show error

Comment: *I try convert script into python the program encounter this error*. Which error? I don't see any errors here. If you restart your kernel from jupyter and run all cells (from the first to the last), does it work?

Comment: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 300 and the array at index 1 has size 6

Comment: I just rerun script all over again.... it still work on part when it happen on jupyter notebook block..... however when I use same code run on python script this statement show me an error

Comment: I think I found a solution it related to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151292/pd-concat-throws-a-valueerror-all-the-input-array-dimensions-except-for-the-con 

it happen when I try concat data that contains with datetime data.

Comment: df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2.astype(df_1.dtypes)],axis = 0, ignore_index=True)